# How to open a webpage on the same tab after redirecting from a link

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a website in which i need to open a HTML page and after a clicked by a user on a link. It will redirect at somewhere. But what i want to open an another link after this redirection within same tab.

For example : I am on my 4shared.com account and when i click on a link to download something. after successfully redirect of that download link. It will automatically open an another link with in same page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your question? It's not clear from your description what the problem is and how we can help you.

Comment: I just put an example. There is a link on my web page which download a file from 4shared.com. I want that when someone click on that url then required download will start as well as it will redirect on another page

Comment: Then just open the download link in a new window and redirect the old one to where you want it to redirect to.

Comment: I want to do this on a single click and in a same tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use php.

Lets say that I click on a download link. It would most probably bring me to a download.php page. It could download the file and then use an if statement (excuse my bad syntax, I usually do bash and C):

`<?php
// download code, or any other code
if (file is downloaded) {
header( 'Location: http://url.of.target' ) ;
} else {
// do nothing and continue downloading
}
?>`